# Using Exim to remove e-mails from one sender

Tags: linux, email, exim

```
2012-11-15 09:24:03 1TZ0MN-0000Tm-2W <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:09 1TZ0MS-0000UH-Jq <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:13 1TZ0MX-0000Us-Me <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:20 1TZ0Md-0000VI-Rh <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:24 1TZ0Mi-0000Vf-KQ <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:30 1TZ0Mn-0000W6-TR <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:36 1TZ0Mt-0000WY-SR <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:41 1TZ0Mz-0000XI-1S <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:45 1TZ0N3-0000Xi-Mz <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
2012-11-15 09:24:51 1TZ0N9-0000YI-FX <= USER@HOST.DOMAIN.TLD U=USER P=local S=439 T="http://USER-DOMAIN.net" for SENTTO@yahoo.com
```

Is there a way to go in and drop all their e-mails? They have 1000s in there.

I tried:

```
exiqgrep -ir SENTTO@yahoo.com | xargs exim -Mrm
exim: no message ids given after -Mrm option
```

Comment: What's (a sample of) the output of the first half of that command?

Comment: Blank. Also tried using the user@host as well. Blank. Maybe I followed the instructions off google wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For me below worked perfect:

To delete all emails from any sender in exim queue use:

## exiqgrep -i -f email@email.com | xargs exim -Mrm

To delete all emails to any receiver in exim queue use:

## exiqgrep -i -r email@email.com | xargs exim -Mrm

Below are exiqgrep and exim commands help:

exiqgrep -h
Exim message queue display utility.
    -h      This help message.
Selection criteria:

```
-f <regexp> Match sender address sender (field is "< >" wrapped)
-r <regexp> Match recipient address
-s <regexp> Match against the size field from long output
-y <seconds>    Message younger than
-o <seconds>    Message older than
-z      Frozen messages only (exclude non-frozen)
-x      Non-frozen messages only (exclude frozen)
```

Display options:
    -c      Display match count
    -l      Long Format [Default]
    -i      Message IDs only
    -b      Brief Format
    -R      Reverse order

EXIM Command:

```
 exim -bp - shows messages in queue
exim -bpc - shows the no.of messages in queue
exim -bP - shows the current configurations of exim
exim -bV - shows the version and configuration file of exim
exiwhat - Finding out what Exim processes are doing
exim -qf - Force another queue run
exim -qff - Force another queue run and attempt to flush frozen messages
exim -Mvl - messageID View Log for message
exim -Mvb - messageID View Body for message
exim -Mvh - messageID View Header for message
exim -Mrm - messageID Remove message (no errors sent)
exim -Mg - messageID Give up and fail message, message bounces to sender
exiqgrep -zi
-z : frozen mails only
-i : display message IDs only
exim -M emailID - Force delivery of one message
```

Answer (score 0):

All the examples I can find of using `exiqgrep` have the options separated, never combined.

Try `exiqgrep -i -r SENTTO@yahoo.com | xargs exim -Mrm`

Comment: Weird still not getting any. I wonder if CPanel is moving them out because they hit the que limit of 20 per hour. Right now I know the exim log file is flooding from emails not being able to send.

Comment: The next argument after `-r` is a regex.  I wonder if there's anything in your replaced `SENTTO` that has a special meaning in a regular expression.  Try just `exiqgrep -r yahoo.com`.

Comment: If I run just eximgrep I see 3 e-mails (not related) then for a split second I had one as mentioned above but then it was gone. I wonder if CPanel just drops them or something from the que.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

## exiqgrep -z -i | xargs exim -Mrm

it work for me to remove all frozen mail from queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all mail from the queue having sender mail address **email@email.com**
try:

```
# exiqgrep -i -f email@email.com | xargs exim -Mg
```

in this you don't have to enter massage id manually one by one... it works for me..